# USB devices not waking PC from sleep on windows 8.1

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, sleep, power-management

I have a new build based on MSI H97M-g43 motherboard.
None of USB devices are able to wake the PC back from S3 sleep.

Two methods that do wake up the PC are the power button and wake timers.
The usb connected keyboard, mouse and IR receiver doesn't.
I've made sure the USB hubs are not powered down by the system. USB devices clearly have power in standby as indicated by LEDs. I've set "allow this device to wake the computer from sleep" in device manager.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is likely that you need to change a setting in the BIOS to allow USB and/or PCI devices to wake from sleep, as well as in Windows Device Manager.